# Python programming probability marble out of a bag coding

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, probability

Hey I'm new to programming but I cant seem to code probability questions. For example, how would I code this?
A box contains 12 transistors of type A and 18 of type B. one transistor is taken out at random and returned. This process is repeated. Determine the probability that the first chosen is type A and second is type B. Thanks!

This is my first try.

```
from  scipy import stats as st
import numpy as np
import random

total=30
totalA=12
totalB=18

def transistor():
    return random.choice("A","B")

random.seed(0)
for _in range(30):
    try1=transistor()
    try2=transistor()

    if try1="A":
        prob1=totalA/total
    else:
        prob1=totalB/total

    if try2="A":
        prob2=totalA/total
    else:
        prob2=totalB/total   

    if try1=="A" and try2=="A"
     prob=2*totalA/total
```

Comment: So you have a `.4` probability to get `A` and `.6` to get `B` and to take `A`, return it and take `B` would be `.24`. Read more about probability [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability).

Comment: `if try1="A":`... Use double equals for comparison

Comment: `transistor()` currently has a 50% chance of both values. You can put 12 A's and 18 B's in that list, and that would be more accurate

Comment: How would you code a problem like this? There are no variables and the answer is the same no matter what. This is a simple math problem that does not need code. If you mean code a simulation, then please clarify in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to run a simulation, this code will give you a probability from 10000 trials. It will generate a different result every time. The more trials, the more accurate it is. The correct, theoretical answer is `0.24`.

```
import random

trials = 10000 # total number of trials
totalA = 12 # total number of A transistors
totalB = 18 # total number of B transistors

successes = 0 # variable keeping track of how many successful pulls there were

choicelist = list("A" * totalA + "B" * totalB) # list containing transitors to correct proportion

def transistor():
    return random.choice(choicelist) # pick a random transistor from list

for i in range(trials):
    try1 = transistor()
    try2 = transistor()
    if try1 == "A" and try2 == "B": # if first pull is type A and second is type B...
        successes += 1 # ...then it's successful
print float(successes) / trials # print out the proportion of successes to trials
```